# bootstrap container div area going beyond parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.X.
I want to limit the child container area to the parent div.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the wrong Bootstrap grid structure. Here is an example of a correct one:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      content 
    </div> <!-- .col -->
  </div> <!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Comment: Are you saying a problem is because of the nested container?

Comment: The problem is in the grid structure. Please, use the correct one: .container > .row > .col